# Picture icon switch effect for Owl Carousel plugin using only CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, hover, owl-carousel

I am not a coder by trade but work with Wordpress sites on the job. I am currently using a plugin that uses Owl Carousel and I added custom CSS to change the background and text color once a segment of the carousel is hovered over. I would also like the current icon symbol (that is a png image) to be changed as well.

I have had difficulty with this and wanted to know if it's even possible using CSS alone, since I don't work in the backend of the site.

You can find an image below of what I would like to accomplish plus. Here is also a link.

[image]

https://www.radiustheme.com/demo/wordpress/miako/home-3/
(this is not the theme I am using but I believe Owl Carousel is also being used.)

Any advice or suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there's a couple of different ways to accomplish this, the first being the easiest and probably most used nowadays in web, and it's utilizing SVG's rather than PNG's for specific elements like icons which are required to change color when hovered.

SVG's make it very easy to do this, you can set an ID, or a class to an SVG element, and simply trigger a change of color of said SVG via CSS with using the hover attribute. Example **[HERE](https://codepen.io/luiscarvalho/pen/hJFrx)**

Alternatively, if the viewers of the website are on a modern browser, you can use CSS filter to change the brightness of the image upon hover, here's an example of that. If it's not bright enough, increase the percentage of brightness until it's white enough:

```
filter: brightness(150%);
-webkit-filter: brightness(150%);
-moz-filter: brightness(150%);
-o-filter: brightness(150%);
-ms-filter: brightness(150%);
```

Comment: Thank you for making me aware of the options I have with SVG files. The link and code you provided were also extremely helpful!

Comment: Also, don't forget that there's a number of free to use icon frameworks out there which are very easy to use and integrate. Personally, I use font-awesome religiously, and changing colors of said icons is very simple via CSS, simply done by changing the color attribute. Source: https://fontawesome.com/

If you need more information let me know! If not, be sure to accept the answer if the information provided works out for you. :)

Comment: My team didn't want to use SVG files for security reasons (not sure about the details there) and while the brightness filter didn't get the desired result, I was able to uses invert(100%) and it worked perfectly. I wouldn't have known about the filter property if not for your answer so thank you again!